# How do I get a list of properties from my EJS template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm storing response strings in a database in EJS form and filling out the data in Node. What I want to do is be able to use *any* property I want, no matter what model it comes from, then in Node, async/await those models once I have the template, based around what properties are required.

So if I have a template like:

```
"Hello <%=user.firstName%>."
```

I want to be able to look at that template and extract something like:

```
ejsProperties = ["user", "user.firstName"]
```

Or something like that.

Comment: As I understand this question, you want to pull out properties from the ejs template and not from the html file right ? and where is `<%=user.firstName%>` user data is stored now, how are you injecting into the template.

Comment: Yes, I would like to pull the data from the template pre-rendered with data. Then depending on the objects required, I could get those models from a DB, then res.render(_template_, _fullObject_)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to pull out simple things like `user.firstName` then running a RegExp over the EJS file is probably as good a way as any. Chances are you'd be looking for a specific and known set of objects and properties so you could target them specifically rather than trying to extract all possible objects/properties.

In the more general case things get difficult very quickly. Something like this is very tricky to handle:

```
<% var u = user; %><%= u.firstName %>
```

It's a silly example but it's just the tip of that particular iceberg. Whereas `user` is being read from the `locals` and is an object of interest, `u` could be just about anything and we can't easily draw lines connecting `firstName` and `user` via `u`. Similarly something like a `forEach` on an array or a `for/in` on an object will quickly make it impossible to link properties to the appropriate `locals` entry.

However, what we can do is identify the entries in `locals`, or at least something very close to that.

Using the example of `<%= user.firstName %>` the identifier `user` could refer to one of 3 things. Firstly, it could be an entry in the `locals`. Secondly, it could be a property of the global object. Thirdly, it could be a variable created within the scope of the template (like `u` in the earlier example).

We can't really tell the difference between the first two cases but chances are you can separate out the globals pretty easily. Things like `console` and `Math` can be identified and discarded.

The third case is the tricky one, telling the difference between an entry in the `locals` and a variable in the template, like in this example:

```
<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
    <%= user.firstName %>
<% }); %>
```

In this case `users` is coming directly from the `locals` but `user` is not. For us to work that out requires variable scope analysis similar to that found in an IDE.

So here's what I tried:

1. Compile the template to JS.
2. Parse the JS into an AST using [esprima](http://esprima.org).
3. Walk the AST to find all the identifiers. If they appear to be global they get returned. Here 'global' means either genuinely global or that they're an entry in the `locals` object. EJS uses `with (locals) {...}` internally so there really is no way to know which one it is.

I've imaginatively called the result `ejsprima`.

I haven't attempted to support all the options that EJS supports, so if you're using custom delimiters or strict mode it won't work. (If you're using strict mode you have to explicitly write `locals.user.firstName` in your template anyway, which is crying out to be done via a RegExp instead). It won't attempt to follow any `include` calls.

I'd be very surprised if there aren't bugs lurking somewhere, even with some piece of basic JS syntax, but I've tested all of the nasty cases I could think of. Test cases are included.

The EJS used in the main demo can be found at the top of the HTML. I've included a gratuitous example of a 'global write' just to demonstrate what they look like but I'd imagine that they aren't something you'd normally want. The interesting bit is the `reads` section.

I developed this against esprima 4 but the best CDN version I could find is 2.7.3. The tests all still pass so it doesn't seem to matter too much.

The only code I included in the JS section of the snippet is for 'ejsprima' itself. To run that in Node you should just need to copy it across and tweak the top and bottom to correct the exports and requires stuff.

```js
// Begin 'ejsprima'
(function(exports) {
//var esprima = require('esprima');

// Simple EJS compiler that throws away the HTML sections and just retains the JavaScript code
exports.compile = function(tpl) {
    // Extract the tags
    var tags = tpl.match(/(<%(?!%)[\s\S]*?[^%]%>)/g);

    return tags.map(function(tag) {
        var parse = tag.match(/^(<%[=\-_#]?)([\s\S]*?)([-_]?%>)$/);

        switch (parse[1]) {
            case '<%=':
            case '<%-':
                return ';(' + parse[2] + ');';
            case '<%#':
                return '';
            case '<%':
            case '<%_':
                return parse[2];
        }

        throw new Error('Assertion failure');
    }).join('\n');
};

// Pull out the identifiers for all 'global' reads and writes
exports.extractGlobals = function(tpl) {
    var ast = tpl;

    if (typeof tpl === 'string') {
        // Note: This should be parseScript in esprima 4
        ast = esprima.parse(tpl);
    }

    // Uncomment this line to dump out the AST
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(ast, null, 2));

    var refs = this.processAst(ast);

    var reads = {};
    var writes = {};

    refs.forEach(function(ref) {
        ref.globalReads.forEach(function(key) {
            reads[key] = true;
        });
    });

    refs.forEach(function(ref) {
        ref.globalWrites.forEach(function(key) {
            writes[key] = true;
        })
    });

    return {
        reads: Object.keys(reads),
        writes: Object.keys(writes)
    };
};

exports.processAst = function(obj) {
    var baseScope = {
        lets: Object.create(null),
        reads: Object.create(null),
        writes: Object.create(null),

        vars: Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
            // These are all local to the rendering function
            arguments: true,
            escapeFn: true,
            include: true,
            rethrow: true
        })
    };

    var scopes = [baseScope];

    processNode(obj, baseScope);

    scopes.forEach(function(scope) {
        scope.globalReads = Object.keys(scope.reads).filter(function(key) {
            return !scope.vars[key] && !scope.lets[key];
        });

        scope.globalWrites = Object.keys(scope.writes).filter(function(key) {
            return !scope.vars[key] && !scope.lets[key];
        });

        // Flatten out the prototype chain - none of this is actually used by extractGlobals so we could just skip it
        var allVars = Object.keys(scope.vars).concat(Object.keys(scope.lets)),
            vars = {},
            lets = {};

        // An identifier can either be a var or a let not both... need to ensure inheritance sees the right one by
        // setting the alternative to false, blocking any inherited value
        for (var key in scope.lets) {
            if (hasOwn(scope.lets)) {
                scope.vars[key] = false;
            }
        }

        for (key in scope.vars) {
            if (hasOwn(scope.vars)) {
                scope.lets[key] = false;
            }
        }

        for (key in scope.lets) {
            if (scope.lets[key]) {
                lets[key] = true;
            }
        }

        for (key in scope.vars) {
            if (scope.vars[key]) {
                vars[key] = true;
            }
        }

        scope.lets = Object.keys(lets);
        scope.vars = Object.keys(vars);
        scope.reads = Object.keys(scope.reads);

        function hasOwn(obj) {
            return obj[key] && (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key));
        }
    });

    return scopes;
    
    function processNode(obj, scope) {
        if (!obj) {
            return;
        }
    
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            obj.forEach(function(o) {
                processNode(o, scope);
            });
    
            return;
        }

        switch(obj.type) {
            case 'Identifier':
                scope.reads[obj.name] = true;
                return;

            case 'VariableDeclaration':
                obj.declarations.forEach(function(declaration) {
                    // Separate scopes for var and let/const
                    processLValue(declaration.id, scope, obj.kind === 'var' ? scope.vars : scope.lets);
                    processNode(declaration.init, scope);
                });

                return;

            case 'AssignmentExpression':
                processLValue(obj.left, scope, scope.writes);

                if (obj.operator !== '=') {
                    processLValue(obj.left, scope, scope.reads);
                }

                processNode(obj.right, scope);

                return;

            case 'UpdateExpression':
                processLValue(obj.argument, scope, scope.reads);
                processLValue(obj.argument, scope, scope.writes);

                return;

            case 'FunctionDeclaration':
            case 'FunctionExpression':
            case 'ArrowFunctionExpression':
                var newScope = {
                    lets: Object.create(scope.lets),
                    reads: Object.create(null),
                    vars: Object.create(scope.vars),
                    writes: Object.create(null)
                };

                scopes.push(newScope);

                obj.params.forEach(function(param) {
                    processLValue(param, newScope, newScope.vars);
                });

                if (obj.id) {
                    // For a Declaration the name is accessible outside, for an Expression it is only available inside
                    if (obj.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
                        scope.vars[obj.id.name] = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        newScope.vars[obj.id.name] = true;
                    }
                }

                processNode(obj.body, newScope);

                return;

            case 'BlockStatement':
            case 'CatchClause':
            case 'ForInStatement':
            case 'ForOfStatement':
            case 'ForStatement':
                // Create a new block scope
                scope = {
                    lets: Object.create(scope.lets),
                    reads: Object.create(null),
                    vars: scope.vars,
                    writes: Object.create(null)
                };

                scopes.push(scope);

                if (obj.type === 'CatchClause') {
                    processLValue(obj.param, scope, scope.lets);
                    processNode(obj.body, scope);

                    return;
                }

                break; // Don't return
        }

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            var value = obj[key];
    
            // Labels for break/continue
            if (key === 'label') {
                return;
            }

            if (key === 'left') {
                if (obj.type === 'ForInStatement' || obj.type === 'ForOfStatement') {
                    if (obj.left.type !== 'VariableDeclaration') {
                        processLValue(obj.left, scope, scope.writes);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (obj.computed === false) {
                // MemberExpression, ClassExpression & Property
                if (key === 'property' || key === 'key') {
                    return;
                }
            }
    
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                processNode(value, scope);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // An l-value is something that can appear on the left of an = operator. It could be a simple identifier, as in
    // `var a = 7;`, or something more complicated, like a destructuring. There's a big difference between how we handle
    // `var a = 7;` and `a = 7;` and the 'target' is used to control which of these two scenarios we are in.
    function processLValue(obj, scope, target) {
        nextLValueNode(obj);
    
        function nextLValueNode(obj) {
            switch (obj.type) {
                case 'Identifier':
                    target[obj.name] = true;
                break;
    
                case 'ObjectPattern':
                    obj.properties.forEach(function(property) {
                        if (property.computed) {
                            processNode(property.key, scope);
                        }
    
                        nextLValueNode(property.value);
                    });
                break;
    
                case 'ArrayPattern':
                    obj.elements.forEach(function(element) {
                        nextLValueNode(element);
                    });
                break;
    
                case 'RestElement':
                    nextLValueNode(obj.argument);
                break;
    
                case 'AssignmentPattern':
                    nextLValueNode(obj.left);
                    processNode(obj.right, scope);
                break;
    
                case 'MemberExpression':
                    processNode(obj, scope);
                break;
    
                default: throw new Error('Unknown type: ' + obj.type);
            }
        }
    }
};
})(window.ejsprima = {});
```

```html
<body>
<script type="text/ejs" id="demo-ejs">
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome <%= user.name %></h1>
        <% if (admin) { %>
            <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
        <% } %>
        <ul>
            <% friends.forEach(function(friend, index) { %>
                <li class="<%= index === 0 ? "first" : "" %> <%= friend.name === selected ? "selected" : "" %>"><%= friend.name %></li>
            <% }); %>
        </ul>
        <%
            console.log(user);
            
            exampleWrite = 'some value';
        %>
    </body>
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/esprima/2.7.3/esprima.min.js"></script>
<script>
function runTests() {
    var assertValues = function(tpl, reads, writes) {
        var program = ejsprima.compile(tpl);

        var values = ejsprima.extractGlobals(program);

        reads = reads || [];
        writes = writes || [];

        reads.sort();
        writes.sort();

        if (!equal(reads, values.reads)) {
            console.log('Mismatched reads', reads, values.reads, tpl);
        }

        if (!equal(writes, values.writes)) {
            console.log('Mismatched writes', writes, values.writes, tpl);
        }

        function equal(arr1, arr2) {
            return JSON.stringify(arr1.slice().sort()) === JSON.stringify(arr2.slice().sort());
        }
    };

    assertValues('<% console.log("hello") %>', ['console']);
    assertValues('<% a = 7; %>', [], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% var a = 7; %>');
    assertValues('<% let a = 7; %>');
    assertValues('<% const a = 7; %>');
    assertValues('<% a = 7; var a; %>');
    assertValues('<% var a = 7, b = a + 1, c = d; %>', ['d']);
    assertValues('<% try{}catch(a){a.log()} %>');
    assertValues('<% try{}catch(a){a = 9;} %>');
    assertValues('<% try{}catch(a){b.log()} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% try{}catch(a){}a; %>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% try{}catch(a){let b;}b; %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% try{}finally{let a;}a; %>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% (function(a){a();b();}) %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% (function(a){a();b = 8;}) %>', [], ['b']);
    assertValues('<% (function(a){a();a = 8;}) %>');
    assertValues('<% (function name(a){}) %>');
    assertValues('<% (function name(a){});name(); %>', ['name']);
    assertValues('<% function name(a){} %>');
    assertValues('<% function name(a){}name(); %>');
    assertValues('<% a.map(b => b + c); %>', ['a', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% a.map(b => b + c); b += 6; %>', ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b']);

    assertValues('<% var {a} = {b: c}; %>', ['c']);
    assertValues('<% var {a} = {b: c}; a(); %>', ['c']);
    assertValues('<% var {[d]: a} = {b: c}; a(); %>', ['c', 'd']);
    assertValues('<% var {[d]: a} = {b: c}; a(); %>', ['c', 'd']);
    assertValues('<% var {[d + e]: a} = {b: c}; a(); %>', ['c', 'd', 'e']);
    assertValues('<% var {[d + e[f = g]]: a} = {b: c}; a(); %>', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'g'], ['f']);
    assertValues('<% ({a} = {b: c}); %>', ['c'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% ({a: d.e} = {b: c}); %>', ['c', 'd']);
    assertValues('<% ({[a]: d.e} = {b: c}); %>', ['a', 'c', 'd']);
    assertValues('<% var {a = 7} = {}; %>', []);
    assertValues('<% var {a = b} = {}; %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% var {[a]: b = (c + d)} = {}; %>', ['a', 'c', 'd']);

    assertValues('<% var [a] = [b]; a(); %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% var [{a}] = [b]; a(); %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% [{a}] = [b]; %>', ['b'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% [...a] = [b]; %>', ['b'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% let [...a] = [b]; %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% var [a = b] = [c]; %>', ['b', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% var [a = b] = [c], b; %>', ['c']);

    assertValues('<% ++a %>', ['a'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% ++a.b %>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% var a; ++a %>');
    assertValues('<% a += 1 %>', ['a'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% var a; a += 1 %>');

    assertValues('<% a.b = 7 %>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% a["b"] = 7 %>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% a[b] = 7 %>', ['a', 'b']);
    assertValues('<% a[b + c] = 7 %>', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% var b; a[b + c] = 7 %>', ['a', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% a in b; %>', ['a', 'b']);
    assertValues('<% "a" in b; %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% "a" in b.c; %>', ['b']);

    assertValues('<% if (a === b) {c();} %>', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% if (a = b) {c();} else {d = e} %>', ['b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'd']);

    assertValues('<% a ? b : c %>', ['a', 'b', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% var a = b ? c : d %>', ['b', 'c', 'd']);

    assertValues('<% for (a in b) {} %>', ['b'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% for (var a in b.c) {} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% for (let {a} in b) {} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% for ({a} in b) {} %>', ['b'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% for (var {[a + b]: c} in d) {} %>', ['a', 'b', 'd']);
    assertValues('<% for ({[a + b]: c} in d) {} %>', ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']);
    assertValues('<% for (var a in b) {a = a + c;} %>', ['b', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% for (const a in b) console.log(a); %>', ['b', 'console']);
    assertValues('<% for (let a in b) console.log(a); %>', ['b', 'console']);
    assertValues('<% for (let a in b) {let b = 5;} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% for (let a in b) {let b = 5;} console.log(a); %>', ['console', 'a', 'b']);
    assertValues('<% for (const a in b) {let b = 5;} console.log(a); %>', ['console', 'a', 'b']);
    assertValues('<% for (var a in b) {let b = 5;} console.log(a); %>', ['console', 'b']);

    assertValues('<% for (a of b) {} %>', ['b'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% for (var a of b.c) {} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% for (let {a} of b) {} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% for ({a} of b) {} %>', ['b'], ['a']);
    assertValues('<% for (var {[a + b]: c} of d) {} %>', ['a', 'b', 'd']);
    assertValues('<% for ({[a + b]: c} of d) {} %>', ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c']);
    assertValues('<% for (var a of b) {a = a + c;} %>', ['b', 'c']);
    assertValues('<% for (const a of b) console.log(a); %>', ['b', 'console']);
    assertValues('<% for (let a of b) console.log(a); %>', ['b', 'console']);
    assertValues('<% for (let a of b) {let b = 5;} %>', ['b']);
    assertValues('<% for (let a of b) {let b = 5;} console.log(a); %>', ['console', 'a', 'b']);
    assertValues('<% for (const a of b) {let b = 5;} console.log(a); %>', ['console', 'a', 'b']);
    assertValues('<% for (var a of b) {let b = 5;} console.log(a); %>', ['console', 'b']);

    assertValues('<% for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {} %>');
    assertValues('<% for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {} %>', ['len']);
    assertValues('<% for (var i = 0, len ; i < len ; ++i) {} %>');
    assertValues('<% for (i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {} %>', ['i', 'len'], ['i']);
    assertValues('<% for ( ; i < len ; ++i) {} %>', ['i', 'len'], ['i']);
    assertValues('<% var i; for ( ; i < len ; ++i) {} %>', ['len']);
    assertValues('<% for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {i += j;} %>', ['j']);
    assertValues('<% for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) {j += i;} %>', ['j'], ['j']);
    assertValues('<% for (const i = 0; i < 10 ; ++i) console.log(i); %>', ['console']);
    assertValues('<% for (let i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) console.log(i); %>', ['console']);
    assertValues('<% for (let i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {let len = 5;} %>', ['len']);
    assertValues('<% for (let i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {let len = 5;} console.log(i); %>', ['console', 'i', 'len']);
    assertValues('<% for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i) {let len = 5;} console.log(i); %>', ['console', 'len']);

    assertValues('<% while(++i){console.log(i);} %>', ['console', 'i'], ['i']);
    assertValues('<% myLabel:while(true){break myLabel;} %>');

    assertValues('<% var a = `Hello ${user.name}`; %>', ['user']);

    assertValues('<% this; null; true; false; NaN; undefined; %>', ['NaN', 'undefined']);

    // Scoping
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a = 7, b;',
            'let c = 8;',
            'a = b + c - d;',
        
            '{',
                'let e = 6;',
                'f = g + e + b + c;',
            '}',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['d', 'g'], ['f']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a = 7, b;',
            'let c = 8;',
            'a = b + c - d;',
        
            '{',
                'let e = 6;',
                'f = g + e + b + c;',
            '}',
        
            'e = c;',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['d', 'g'], ['e', 'f']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a = 7, b;',
            'let c = 8;',
            'a = b + c - d;',
        
            '{',
                'var e = 6;',
                'f = g + e + b + c;',
            '}',
        
            'e = c;',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['d', 'g'], ['f']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a;',
            'let b;',
            'const c = 0;',
        
            '{',
                'var d;',
                'let e;',
                'const f = 1;',
            '}',
        
            'var g = function h(i) {',
                'arguments.length;',
                'a(); b(); c(); d(); e(); f(); g(); h(); i();',
            '};',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['e', 'f']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a;',
            'let b;',
            'const c = 0;',
        
            '{',
                'var d;',
                'let e;',
                'const f = 1;',
            '}',
        
            'var g = function h(i) {};',
            'arguments.length;',
            'a(); b(); c(); d(); e(); f(); g(); h(); i();',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['e', 'f', 'h', 'i']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a;',
            'let b;',
            'const c = 0;',
        
            '{',
                'var d;',
                'let e;',
                'const f = 1;',
        
                'arguments.length;',
                'a(); b(); c(); d(); e(); f(); g(); h(); i();',
            '}',
        
            'var g = function h(i) {};',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['h', 'i']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a;',
            'let b;',
            'const c = 0;',
        
            '{',
                'var d;',
                'let e;',
                'const f = 1;',
        
                'var g = function h(i) {',
                    'arguments.length;',
                    'a(); b(); c(); d(); e(); f(); g(); h(); i();',
                '};',
            '}',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'));
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a;',
            'let b;',
            'const c = 0;',
        
            'var g = function h(i) {',
                '{',
                    'var d;',
                    'let e;',
                    'const f = 1;',
                '}',
        
                'arguments.length;',
                'a(); b(); c(); d(); e(); f(); g(); h(); i();',
            '};',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'), ['e', 'f']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<%',
            'var a;',
            'let b;',
            'const c = 0;',
        
            'var g = function h(i) {',
                '{',
                    'var d;',
                    'let e;',
                    'const f = 1;',
        
                    'arguments.length;',
                    'a(); b(); c(); d(); e(); f(); g(); h(); i();',
                '}',
            '};',
        '%>'
    ].join('\n'));
        
    // EJS parsing
    assertValues('Hello <%= user.name %>', ['user']);
    assertValues('Hello <%- user.name %>', ['user']);
    assertValues('Hello <%# user.name %>');
    assertValues('Hello <%_ user.name _%>', ['user']);
    assertValues('Hello <%_ user.name _%>', ['user']);
    assertValues('Hello <%% console.log("<%= user.name %>") %%>', ['user']);
    assertValues('Hello <% console.log("<%% user.name %%>") %>', ['console']);
    assertValues('<% %><%a%>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% %><%=a%>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% %><%-a_%>', ['a']);
    assertValues('<% %><%__%>');
        
    assertValues([
        '<body>',
            '<h1>Welcome <%= user.name %></h1>',
            '<% if (admin) { %>',
                '<a href="/admin">Admin</a>',
            '<% } %>',
            '<ul>',
                '<% friends.forEach(function(friend, index) { %>',
                    '<li class="<%= index === 0 ? "first" : "" %> <%= friend.name === selected ? "selected" : "" %>"><%= friend.name %></li>',
                '<% }); %>',
            '</ul>',
        '</body>'
    ].join('\n'), ['user', 'admin', 'friends', 'selected']);
        
    assertValues([
        '<body>',
            '<h1>Welcome <%= user.name %></h1>',
            '<% if (admin) { %>',
                '<a href="/admin">Admin</a>',
            '<% } %>',
            '<ul>',
                '<% friends.forEach(function(user, index) { %>',
                    '<li class="<%= index === 0 ? "first" : "" %> <%= user.name === selected ? "selected" : "" %>"><%= user.name %></li>',
                '<% }); %>',
            '</ul>',
        '</body>'
    ].join('\n'), ['user', 'admin', 'friends', 'selected']);
    
    console.log('Tests complete, if you didn\'t see any other messages then they passed');
}
</script>
<script>
function runDemo() {
    var script = document.getElementById('demo-ejs'),
        tpl = script.innerText,
        js = ejsprima.compile(tpl);
        
    console.log(ejsprima.extractGlobals(js));
}
</script>
<button onclick="runTests()">Run Tests</button>
<button onclick="runDemo()">Run Demo</button>
</body>
```

So, in summary, I believe this will allow you to accurately identify all the required entries for your `locals`. Identifying the properties used within those objects is, in general, not possible. If you don't mind the loss of accuracy then you might as well just use a RegExp.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to run the code yet, will shortly, but this is great response. Thank you for really thinking around the edges.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately EJS doesn't provide functionality for parsing and extracting variable names from template. It has `compile` method, but this method returns a [function](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/lib/ejs.js#L201) which can be used to render a string by template. But you need to get some intermediate result, to extract variables.

You can do that using [Mustache template system](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/).

Mustache default delimiters are `{{ }}`. You can replace them [to custom delimiters](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#custom-delimiters). Unfortunately Mustache doesn't allow to define multiple delimiters (`<%= %>` and `<% %>` for example), so if you'll try to compile template which contains multiple delimiters, Mustache will throw an error. The possible solution for that is to create a function which accepts a template and delimiters, and replaces all other delimeters to something neutral. And call this function for each pair of delimiters:

```
let vars = [];
vars.concat(parseTemplate(template, ['<%', '%>']));
vars.concat(parseTemplate(template, ['<%=', '%>']));
...
let uniqVars = _.uniq(vars);
```

Below the simple variant which works only with one pair of delimiters:

```
let _        = require('lodash');
let Mustache = require('Mustache');

let template = 'Hello <%= user.firstName %> <%= user.lastName %> <%= date %>';
let customTags = ['<%=', '%>'];

let tokens = Mustache.parse(template, customTags);
let vars = _.chain(tokens)
  .filter(token => token[0] === 'name')
  .map(token => {
    let v = token[1].split('.');
    return v;
  })
  .flatten()
  .uniq()
  .value();

console.log(vars); // prints ['user', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'date']
```

Comment: Downvoter,  could you please explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Agree with @alexmac. Why was this down voted? It's not EJS, but it's a good solution if an EJS solution isn't possible.

Comment: I have voted you back up @alexmac just some hater downvoted my answer too, well mine wasn't correct but my comments were.

Comment: @Individual11 I've added a note about EJS, and why it can't be used in your case.

Answer (score -1):

I think `res.locals` is what you are looking for in this case,

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var myUser = {
  user :
    {
    username: 'myUser',
    lastName: 'userLastName',
    location: 'USA'
  }
}

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals = myUser;
  next();
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('file.ejs');
})
```

In any ejs file, we can use the properties as we like,

```
  <body>
    <h3>The User</h3>
    <p><%=user.username%></p>
    <p><%=user.lastName%></p>
    <p><%=user.location%></p>
  </body>
```

Comment: I thought about *.locals*, but I need to get the list of the properties from the template itself, not push the data into the template.

Comment: what do you mean? from the client side? then you should send a post request. if you wanna do it without refreshing the page wait till the dom is loaded, you should use javascript and ajax @Individual11

Comment: No, what I want to do is grab the template, figure out what properties are needed to fill it in, and go fetch them asynchronously before rendering the template. That way I don't need to carry around a ton of data and only get what I need when i need it.

Comment: I don't think there is any module for that kind of purpose, what I would do use `fs` to read the file, check for <%=object%> from the data, check the object names, and do callback and fill them back in by rendering. @Individual11

Comment: a module like that could be created and published, great idea to be honest @Individual11